# Force format not to be overwritten by the environment

Tags: formatting

I have the following macro defined

```
\newcommand\ve[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\textbf{#1}}}}
```

which produces a bold non-italic letter in math-mode. The ensuremath ensures that it will behave the same in math-mode and in text-mode. The problem is when I use it in a theorem: Text in theorems is generally italicized, and for some reason

```
\ve{t}
```

is italicized too. Is there any `\doNotChangeFormat` command such that I can define

```
\newcommand\ve[1]{\doNotChangeFormat{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\textbf{#1}}}}}
```

and be sure that the format I am defined will prevail in any context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 \ensuremath{\mathrm{\textbf{#1}}}}
```

is the same as

```
 \textbf{#1}
```

as `\ensuremath` gets you into math mode but `\textbf` gets you out again.

Math font commands do not combine in the way that text font commands do. I think you just want

```
 \ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}
```

which will always give a bold upright math font.